# How to do regression analysis in SAGA for topographic correction

Tags: saga, analysis, satellite, topography, regression

Currently I am trying to do the topographic correction using C-Correction. I would like to know if there is a way to do the regression analysis between L (uncorrected reflectance of each band from satellite image) and cos i (the incidence angle), to get the C value.

I tried to do the regression analysis using SAGA (the uncorrected reflectance of each band as dependent variable). but I am not sure how to calculate cos i as the independent variable. 
Do you have any advice how to get the "cos i" value?